# Date interval allotment calculation - date calculation

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

guys, here is the situation I suffer from;

I have accommodation products on my database. and under every hotel there are periods which are date intervals for reservations. and under very periods there are room types, their prices and allotments.

so lets say this;

```
 HOTEL A

 01.05.2011 - 25.05.2011
      Room A : 3 Allotment daily, 34 USD
      Room B : 4 Allotment daily, 45 USD
 26.05.2011 - 14.06.2011
      Room A : 3 Allotment daily, 45 USD
      Room B : 4 Allotment daily, 67 USD
```

on the other side there is a reservation table on my data base and it holds the reservation details. lets say this;

a guy made a reservation for ***HOTEL A**** for between ***22.05.2011 - 30.05.2011*** and for Room A. This reservation has been saved to database as well.

the issue is this;

how can I calculate the allotment here? In my example, the Room A allotment needs to be 2 for 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 of May. I need to calculate this because I won't show a room whose allotment is 0 for any date between the requested date interval.

I am using c# entity framework for calculation purposes and my database is on ms sql server. a stored procedure example would also be nice. thatnks !

**EDIT :**
Here is an example code I am trying;

```
    declare @a as table(a date) declare @b as table(b date) insert @a values('2011-05-22') insert @b values('2011-05-30') 

;with e as( select a as dayt,0 as lvl from @a aa

 union all select DATEADD(DAY,1,aa.dayt) as dayt, lvl+1 from @b bb inner join e aa ON aa.dayt<bb.b ) 

select * from e
```

Comment: hmm, looks like a not-interesting topic :S

Comment: Not very clear what kind of change should be made in the underlying tables. In short, what is the expected result (in terms of both storing the data and displaying them)?

Comment: @andriy I am just looking for a rough idea. how can I handle this issue here? I need to play with datetime here, but in which way I need to play, I am not sure on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

Step 1: for each reservation determine the periods that the reservation start/end overlap. You can join based on (reservation_end >= period_start and reservation_start <= period_end). This should return the periods that the reservation overlaps.

Step 2: subtract out the allotments for each period. I am not sure how you get 2 allotments in your example with only 1 reservation so can't tell you exactly how to do this math.

I cannot provide specific examples unless I know the data model and some sample data. Are you able to provide these?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I updated my qu. please see an t-sql example. do u think I got that right? actually, the code has been written by someone else who suggested that it could work on my case.

Comment: not really sure how that code applies to anything you are trying to accomplish. what do your tables look like? column names, structure, etc. if you dont know that then no one is really going to be able to assist.

Comment: u are right. I'm gonna give it a try myself and see what I can do. thanks.